# Как в Filterrific не сохранять фильтры пользователя?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gems

Из коробки в Filterrific выбранные пользователем фильтры сохраняются в cookie. То есть сортировка по параметрам или ключевым словам сбрасывается только в том случае, если пользователь нажмет на соответствующую кнопку.

Иными словами, поиск по сайту с использованием Filterrific не зависит от URL параметров в адресной строке.

Как отключить эту опцию - сохранение выбранных пользователем фильтров в cookie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну [документация](http://filterrific.clearcove.ca/pages/action_controller_api.html) же. Это определяется в параметрах `initialize_filterrific`:

```
#     * persistence_id: optional, defaults to "<controller>#<action>" string
#       to isolate session persistence of multiple filterrific instances.
#       Override this to share session persisted filter params between
#       multiple filterrific instances. Set to `false` to disable session
#       persistence.
```

Нужно поставить `:persistence_id` в `false`.

Comment: Балин. Я прошелся по тексту документации по ключевому слову `coo` (от `cookie`). А оказывается надо было `session`... Спасибо :)